# MPI Send and Recv struct

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi

My first process creates a linked List of structs and I want to send one element of the list to each process. I need to pass a grid to callMethod() after receiving the element in other processes. Do I need to convert these first before sending in MPI?

```
struct grid {
    int g[N][N];
};

typedef struct s_grids {
    struct grid grid;
    int start;
    struct grids* next;
} grids;

    (...MPI_Initialization...) 
    grids* gridList;
    if (rank == 0)
    {
        gridList= initParallel(process_count, &possibleSolutionsCount);
        // Send one Grid to each process
        grids* ptr;
        ptr = gridList;
        for (int i = 0; i < process_count; i++)
        {
            MPI_Send(&ptr->grid, sizeof(ptr), ...);
            ptr = gridList->next;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Receive struct element
        MPI_Recv(...)
        // Pass strcut element to a function 
        callMethod(struct grid g)
    }
(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't send a pointer to another processes (or MPI rank in this specific example) and expect it to be meaningful on the other end.

What you want to do is to send the actual data. For a data structure that uses pointers to connect nodes this entails converting it to a serialized form without pointers. Say for a linked list, convert it to an array, or for a tree you can put all the elements in an array, and instead of child/parent pointers you have integer indices to the array.

Comment: In this case i want to send a grid/2d array (Edited it to &ptr-grid when sending, my bad). But a 2D array is a 1d array with pointers in C isnt it? So do I need to send 9 1d Arrays instead?

Comment: @KamilJu: In general it's better in C to store a NxM 2D array as a N \* M 1D array, and then to access the (i,j) element with array[i*M + j]. That also makes it easier to serialize for MPI.

Comment: "a 2D array is a 1d array with pointers in C isnt it? " No it isn't.